# Calculate the mode whilst ignoring certain values

Tags: python, numpy

How can I get the mode in numpy? With the caveat that I want to ignore certain values?

For example;

```
[[-1, 2, -1],
 [2, -1, -1],
 [2, 45, 1]]
```

In the above the mode is `-1` but I want to ignore all -1 values always so the mode should be `2` in the above example. I want to determine the mode and how many times it occurs (`3` in the above example).

My iterative function is below:

```
def calc_mode(values, ignore_value=-1):

    if values.sum() == ignore_value * values.size:
        return -1

    mode_map = {}

    for (x,y), value in np.ndenumerate(values):
        if (value <= ignore_value):
            continue

        if not value in mode_map:
            mode_map[value] = 1
        else:
            mode_map[value] += 1

    if len(mode_map) <= 0:
        return -1

    mode = max(zip(mode_map.values(), mode_map.keys()))
    return mode[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even have to flatten the array if you don't want. Fancy indexing is fantastic. Additionally, you can avoid the conversion to an `numpy.ndarray` object if `values` is already an array.

```
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np

def calc_mode(values, ignore_value=-1):
    values = np.array(values)
    return scipy.stats.mode(values[values!=ignore_value]).mode[0]
```